# MySQL select WITHOUT ignoring duplicates?

Tags: mysql

How would I select rows and display them WITHOUT ignoring any duplicate values? I just want them displayed as is regardless of the query or value repeating?

I have 2 DBs which I need to pull info from. The first DB has the Customer's Invoice number and the customer ID, from here I get the customer ID for all the invoices. Some customers might just have 1 Invoice while another customer might have 3 invoices. Now, once this data is pulled, I go to the second database and pull all the phone numbers of that customer using user id. Here is what my query looks like.

```
SELECT number FROM `db_name` WHERE `userid`=594 AND `customid`= 8 UNION
SELECT number FROM `db_name` WHERE `userid`=147 AND `customid`= 8 UNION
SELECT number FROM `db_name` WHERE `userid`=147 AND `customid`= 8 UNION
SELECT number FROM `db_name` WHERE `userid`=436 AND `customid`= 8
```

Now, as you can see, the middle 2 queries are repeating for the same userid, however I need them as is because this data goes into an excel sheet and there are 2 invoice numbers waiting for the customer telephone number as input in the column beside them.

The output of the query is:

```
9123456789
8987123456
9987654321
```

Is there a way I can get MySQL to give me the values regardless of them being duplicate queries? The only alternative I have is to use the output and then do a vlookup in excel for customer id, which is going to be a pain every time I want the results.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: [UNION ALL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html)

Comment: The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result. The optional DISTINCT keyword has no effect other than the default because it also specifies duplicate-row removal. With the optional ALL keyword, duplicate-row removal does not occur and the result includes all matching rows from all the SELECT statements.

Comment: Try to use UNION ALL instead of UNION

Comment: Thank you everyone! UNION ALL worked. I can't believe it was that simple, I'm feel like facepalming myself now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT number FROM `db_name` WHERE `userid`=594 AND `customid`= 8 UNION ALL
SELECT number FROM `db_name` WHERE `userid`=147 AND `customid`= 8 UNION ALL
SELECT number FROM `db_name` WHERE `userid`=147 AND `customid`= 8 UNION ALL
```

SELECT number FROM `db_name` WHERE `userid`=436 AND `customid`= 8